# How to make a function that zips two tuples in C++11 (STL)?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, template-meta-programming

*I recently ran across this puzzle, was finally able to struggle out a hacky answer (using index arrays), and wanted to share it (answer below). I am sure there are answers that use template recursion and answers that use `boost`; if you're interested, please share other ways to do this. I think having these all in one place may benefit others and be useful for learning some of the cool C++11 template metaprogramming tricks.*

**Problem:**
Given two tuples of equal length:

```
auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1, 'b', -10);
auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(2.5, 2, std::string("even strings?!"));
```

How do you create a function that will "zip" the two tuples into a heterogeneous tuple of pairs?

```
std::tuple<
    std::pair<int, double>,
    std::pair<char, int>,
    std::pair<int, std::string> > result =
    tuple_zip( tup1, tup2 );
```

Where

```
std::get<0>(result) == std::make_pair(1, 2.5);
std::get<1>(result) == std::make_pair('b', 2);
std::get<2>(result) == std::make_pair(-10, std::string("even strings?!"));
```

Comment: And now for the bonus: 1/ Can you make it work even for tuples of unequal lengths (padding with `nullptr_t` for example) ? and more involved 2/ Can you make it work with an arbitrary number of tuples ?

Comment: What do you mean with *zip two tuples*? Can you post expected result?

Comment: @BЈовић I've added the desired output of the final `main` routine to the answer below. By zip, I mean take the two tuples above (`tup1` and `tup2`) and create a tuple of 3 elements in this case, where the first is `make_pair(1, 2.5)`, etc.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Voila! Edit below has padding for tuples of different sizes. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**First, a quick overview of index arrays:**

```
template<std::size_t ...S>
struct seq { };

// And now an example of how index arrays are used to print a tuple:
template <typename ...T, std::size_t ...S>
void print_helper(std::tuple<T...> tup, seq<S...> s) {
  // this trick is exceptionally useful:
  // ((std::cout << std::get<S>(tup) << " "), 0) executes the cout
  // and returns 0.
  // { 0... } expands (because the expression has an S in it),
  // returning an array of length sizeof...(S) full of zeros.
  // The array isn't used, but it's a great hack to do one operation
  // for each std::size_t in S.
  int garbage[] = { ((std::cout << std::get<S>(tup) << " "), 0)... };
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And now to use our print_helper function:

```
int main() {
  print_helper(std::make_tuple(10, 0.66, 'h'), seq<0,1,2>() );
  return 0;
}
```

Typing `seq<0,1,2>` can be a bit of a pain, though. So we can use template recursion to create a class to generate `seq`s, so that `gens<3>::type` is the same as `seq<0,1,2>`:

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<std::size_t ...S>
struct gens<0, S...> {
  typedef seq<S...> type;
};

int main() {
  print_helper(std::make_tuple(10, 0.66, 'h'), gens<3>::type() );
  return 0;
}
```

Since the `N` in `gens<N>::type` will always be the number of elements in the tuple, you can wrap `print_helper` to make it easier:

```
template <typename ...T>
void print(std::tuple<T...> tup) {
  print_helper(tup, typename gens<sizeof...(T)>::type() );
}

int main() {
  print(std::make_tuple(10, 0.66, 'h'));
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the template arguments can be deduced automatically (typing all of that out would be a pain wouldn't it?).

**Now, the `tuple_zip` function:**

As before, start with the helper function:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
    template <typename ...> class Tup2,
    typename ...A, typename ...B,
    std::size_t ...S>
auto tuple_zip_helper(Tup1<A...> t1, Tup2<B...> t2, seq<S...> s) ->
decltype(std::make_tuple(std::make_pair(std::get<S>(t1),std::get<S>(t2))...)) {
  return std::make_tuple( std::make_pair( std::get<S>(t1), std::get<S>(t2) )...);
}
```

The code is a little tricky, particularly the trailing return type (the return type is declared as `auto` and provided with `->` after the parameters are defined). This lets us avoid the problem of even *defining* what the return type will be, by simply declaring it returns the expression used in the function body (if `x` and `y` are `int`s, `delctype(x+y)` is resolved at compile time as `int`).

Now wrap it in a function that provides the appropriate `seq<0, 1...N>` using `gens<N>::type`:

```
template <template <typename ...> class Tup1,
  template <typename ...> class Tup2,
  typename ...A, typename ...B>
auto tuple_zip(Tup1<A...> t1, Tup2<B...> t2) ->
decltype(tuple_zip_helper(t1, t2, typename gens<sizeof...(A)>::type() )) {
  static_assert(sizeof...(A) == sizeof...(B), "The tuple sizes must be the same");
  return tuple_zip_helper( t1, t2, typename gens<sizeof...(A)>::type() );
}
```

Now you can use it as specified in the question:

```
int main() {
  auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1, 'b', -10);
  auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(2.5, 2, std::string("even strings?!"));
  std::tuple<
    std::pair<int, double>,
    std::pair<char, int>,
    std::pair<int, std::string> > x = tuple_zip( tup1, tup2 );

  // this is also equivalent:
  //  auto x = tuple_zip( tup1, tup2 );

  return 0;
}
```

And finally, if you provide a `<<` operator for `std::pair` you can use the print function we defined above to print the zipped result:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const std::pair<A, B> & pair) {
  os << "pair("<< pair.first << "," << pair.second << ")";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1, 'b', -10);
  auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(2.5, 2, std::string("even strings?!"));
  auto x = tuple_zip( tup1, tup2 );

  std::cout << "zipping: ";
  print(tup1);
  std::cout << "with   : ";
  print(tup2);

  std::cout << "yields : ";
  print(x);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> zipping: 1 b 10
>   with   : 2.5 2 even strings?!
>   yields : pair(1,2.5) pair(b,2) pair(10,even strings?!)

Like `std::array`, `std::tuple` is defined at compile time, and so it can be used to generate more optimizable code (more information is known at compile time compared to containers like `std::vector` and `std::list`). So even though it's sometimes a bit of work, you can sometimes use it to make fast and clever code. Happy hacking!

---

**Edit:**

As requested, allowing tuples of different sizes and padding with null pointers:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ...S>
auto array_to_tuple_helper(const std::array<T, N> & arr, seq<S...> s) -> decltype(std::make_tuple(arr[S]...)) {
  return std::make_tuple(arr[S]...);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
auto array_to_tuple(const std::array<T, N> & arr) -> decltype( array_to_tuple_helper(arr, typename gens<N>::type()) ) {
  return array_to_tuple_helper(arr, typename gens<N>::type());
}

template <std::size_t N, template <typename ...> class Tup, typename ...A>
auto pad(Tup<A...> tup) -> decltype(tuple_cat(tup, array_to_tuple(std::array<std::nullptr_t, N>()) )) {
  return tuple_cat(tup, array_to_tuple(std::array<std::nullptr_t, N>()) );
}

#define EXTENSION_TO_FIRST(first,second) ((first)>(second) ? (first)-(second) : 0)

template <template <typename ...> class Tup1, template <typename ...> class Tup2, typename ...A, typename ...B>
auto pad_first(Tup1<A...> t1, Tup2<B...> t2) -> decltype( pad<EXTENSION_TO_FIRST(sizeof...(B), sizeof...(A)), Tup1, A...>(t1) ) {
  return pad<EXTENSION_TO_FIRST(sizeof...(B), sizeof...(A)), Tup1, A...>(t1);
}

template <template <typename ...> class Tup1, template <typename ...> class Tup2, typename ...A, typename ...B>
auto diff_size_tuple_zip(Tup1<A...> t1, Tup2<B...> t2) ->
  decltype( tuple_zip( pad_first(t1, t2), pad_first(t2, t1) ) ) {
  return tuple_zip( pad_first(t1, t2), pad_first(t2, t1) );
}
```

And BTW, you're going to need this now to use our handy `print` function:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, std::nullptr_t) {
  os << "null_ptr";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: Nice overall solution. I'll only have a couple of remarks. 1/ I would use `unsigned` as indexes (at the very least), because you don't expect negatives indexes, do you ? 2/ A `static_assert` instead of the `assert` would be welcome. 3/ The pair should probably be taken by `const&` in the `operator<<` overload.

Comment: Generalizing `tuple_zip` to operate on an arbitrary number of tuples left as an exercise to the reader ? :)

Comment: For the unequal ones, I think I'd use `decltype(std::ignore)` instead of `std::nullptr_t`, because I think it plays nicer: it allows distinction from an actual tuple with `std::nullptr_t`, and still works ok with tuples of references. Also, it's a pity that the standard tuple_cat is not required to work with arrays (even when `std::get` overloads exist for them) forcing extra copies :( I had to resort to implementing my own tuple_cat.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Fingers crossed the compiler takes them out with copy propagation...

Comment: Your print_helper cannot print zero-size tuples (zero-size automatic arrays are not allowed).

Answer (score 2):

It isn't extremely difficult to do this for an arbitrary amount of tuples.

One way is to make a function that collects all elements at a specific index from N tuples into a new tuple. Then have another function which collects those tuples into a new tuple for each index in the original tuples.

All of that can be done relatively simply by expanding expressions with parameter packs, without any recursive functions.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {
    // Describe the type of a tuple with element I from each input tuple.
    // Needed to preserve the exact types from the input tuples.
    template<std::size_t I, typename... Tuples>
    using zip_tuple_at_index_t = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::decay_t<Tuples>>...>;

    // Collect all elements at index I from all input tuples as a new tuple.
    template<std::size_t I, typename... Tuples>
    zip_tuple_at_index_t<I, Tuples...> zip_tuple_at_index(Tuples && ...tuples) {
        return {std::get<I>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...};
    }

    // Create a tuple with the result of zip_tuple_at_index for each index.
    // The explicit return type prevents flattening into a single tuple
    // when sizeof...(Tuples) == 1 or sizeof...(I) == 1 .
    template<typename... Tuples, std::size_t... I>
    std::tuple<zip_tuple_at_index_t<I, Tuples...>...> tuple_zip_impl(Tuples && ...tuples, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return {zip_tuple_at_index<I>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...)...};
    }

}

// Zip a number of tuples together into a tuple of tuples.
// Take the first tuple separately so we can easily get its size.
template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
auto tuple_zip(Head && head, Tail && ...tail) {
    constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Head>>;

    static_assert(
        ((std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tail>> == size) && ...),
        "Tuple size mismatch, can not zip."
    );

    return detail::tuple_zip_impl<Head, Tail...>(
        std::forward<Head>(head),
        std::forward<Tail>(tail)...,
        std::make_index_sequence<size>()
    );
}
```

See it in action here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/EQhvLPyRfDrtjDMw

I used some C++14/17 features, but nothing essential. The most difficult part to replace would be the fold expression for checking the tuple sizes. That would probably have to become a recursive check.